# Fast way of filtering pandas dataframes according to element positions in another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working with 3 pandas dataframes that contain information about differential gene expression for multiple cell groups. It's essentially a multi-dimentional dataframe, where one dataframe (names) is the index of where to look for in the p-value and foldchange dataframes for the corresponding values.

```python
columns = ['g0','g1','g2','g3']
names = pd.DataFrame(data = [
   ['Fxyd3', 'Apoe', 'Apoe', 'Apoe'],
   ['Apoe', 'Hspg2', 'Hspg2', 'Ltbp3'],
   ['Tpm1', 'Ltbp3', 'Ltbp3', 'Hspg2'],
   ['App', 'Serpinh1', 'Fxyd3', 'Fxyd3'],
   ['Ltbp3', 'Fxyd3', 'Serpinh1', 'Lgr5'],
   ['Hspg2', 'Lgr5', 'Lgr5', 'App'],
   ['Slc6a6', 'App', 'App', 'Serpinh1'],
   ['Serpinh1', 'Slc6a6', 'Slc6a6', 'Slc6a6'],
   ['Lgr5', 'Tpm1', 'Tpm1', 'Tpm1'],
   ['Krt15', 'Krt15', 'Krt15', 'Krt15']], 
   columns = columns)

np.random.seed(0)
pvalues = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(10,4)/100, columns = columns)
foldchanges = pd.DataFrame(data =np.random.rand(10,4)*100, columns = columns)
```

What I would like to do is to find the minimum p-value for each gene and the corresponding foldchange and group name. After hours of trying to wrap my head around this, I came to this solution:

```python
gene_set = ['Hspg2', 'Ltbp3', 'Lgr5', 'Krt15', 'Serpinh1', 'Tpm1', 'App', 'Apoe', 'Slc6a6', 'Fxyd3']
df = pd.DataFrame(index = gene_set, columns = ['pvalues', 'foldchanges', 'group'], data = 0)

for gene in gene_set:
    bool_df = names.values == gene
    values = pvalues.values[bool_df]
    df['pvalues'].loc[gene] = min(values)
    df['foldchanges'].loc[gene] = foldchanges.values[bool_df][values==min(values)]  
    values = pvalues.T.values[bool_df.T] #Fix to get out correct group name
    df['group'].loc[gene] = columns[np.where(values==min(values))[0][0]]
```

Resulting in an output like this:

```python
           pvalues  foldchanges group
Hspg2     0.004376    21.038256    g2
Ltbp3     0.000202    65.310833    g0
Lgr5      0.004562    97.676109    g0
Krt15     0.006121    28.280696    g0
Serpinh1  0.005218    83.794491    g0
Tpm1      0.000188    73.926358    g2
App       0.001434    82.099323    g2
Apoe      0.004237    66.676672    g0
Slc6a6    0.001183    19.658236    g0
Fxyd3     0.000710    20.887676    g2
```

Now, my issue is that in the full dataset, I have 20+ groups and around 50,000 genes, which ends up taking about 15-20 minutes to run. And I would like to run this code for multiple datasets. So I was wondering if there maybe is a more elegant and faster way to achieve the same goal?

**Edit:** Added random seed for reproducibility and added a fix to get out correct group names

Comment: kindly add `random.seed(..)` to your data, so results is the same when others are testing, and looking for better solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is essential to have all relevant data in the body of the dataframe and in this sense, the `melt()` function is an important ally to organize your data.

```
df_melted = pd.melt(pvalues, var_name="group", value_name="pvalues")
df_melted['foldchanges'] = pd.melt(foldchanges, var_name="group", value_name="foldchanges")['foldchanges']
df_melted['gene'] = pd.melt(names, var_name="group", value_name="gene")['gene']
```

Now, you can simply do some basic grouping to get the indexes with the minimum `pvalues`

```
min_idx = df_melted.groupby(by=["gene"])["pvalues"].idxmin()
out_df = df_melted.iloc[min_idx]
```

Some formatting to get the output on the format you want

```
out_df = out_df.set_index('gene').rename_axis(None)[['pvalues', 'foldchanges', 'group']]
```

And you are good to go

```
           pvalues  foldchanges group
Apoe      0.004237    66.676672    g0
App       0.001434    82.099323    g2
Fxyd3     0.000710    20.887676    g2
Hspg2     0.004376    21.038256    g2
Krt15     0.006121    28.280696    g0
Lgr5      0.004562    97.676109    g0
Ltbp3     0.000202    65.310833    g0
Serpinh1  0.005218    83.794491    g0
Slc6a6    0.001183    19.658236    g0
Tpm1      0.000188    73.926358    g2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is approach worked perfectly and took only about 12 seconds to complete! (I keep forgetting about the melt function in pandas)
The code line `df['group'].loc[gene] = columns[np.where(values==min(values))[0][0]]` that gives a wrong result, I figured out it's because the selected values come in the order of appearance in the rows, not in the columns, that's why it reported the wrong column name. I added an ugly fix to it in the main code.

Comment: @Karl I am glad this helped. Would you mind not only accepting my answer but also upvoting it as it was useful for you? Also, as you have found the error on this code `df['group'].loc[gene] = columns[np.where(values==min(values))[0][0]]` could you update your question with it? It might help people looking for a similar issue in the future or people with better answers trying to replicate your problem.

Comment: My account is too new for my upvotes to be visible. And I already added this line `values = pvalues.T.values[bool_df.T] #Fix to get out correct group name` to fix the issue by transposing the dataframes before filtering (it was the easiest fix I could come up with).

Comment: @Karl Ok, sorry I had not seen the new code. However, the output is still different from the one I got, why is that? PS: I think that now you got enough rep for upvotes. ;)

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten to update the output, sorry about that! Now that's corrected too and the only difference from your output is the row order.

Comment: @Karl Excellent! I will edit my answer to remove the final note. Also, thank you for upvoting all answers you consider useful.

Answer (score 1):

I want to avoid looping to speed up the process. So we recombine the three data frames into a long format. Group them together in a new data frame and aggregate the minimum p-value. Extract a new data frame with the obtained gene names and P-values. What differs from your logic is the timing of the extraction of the group names. The group name corresponding to the P-value is obtained from the beginning. If this approach is wrong, we can only help you speed up the process partially. Thank you for your understanding.

```
g0 = pd.concat([names['g0'],pvalues['g0'],foldchanges['g0']],axis=1)
g0.columns = ['names','pvalues','foldchanges']
g0['group'] = 'g0'

g1 = pd.concat([names['g1'],pvalues['g1'],foldchanges['g1']],axis=1)
g1.columns = ['names','pvalues','foldchanges']
g1['group'] = 'g1'

g2 = pd.concat([names['g2'],pvalues['g2'],foldchanges['g2']],axis=1)
g2.columns = ['names','pvalues','foldchanges']
g2['group'] = 'g2'

g3 = pd.concat([names['g3'],pvalues['g3'],foldchanges['g3']],axis=1)
g3.columns = ['names','pvalues','foldchanges']
g3['group'] = 'g3'

all_df = pd.concat([g0, g1, g2, g3], axis=0)

gb = all_df.groupby('names')['pvalues'].agg('min').reset_index()
all_df[(all_df['names'].isin(gb['names'])) & (all_df['pvalues'].isin(gb['pvalues']))]

    names   pvalues foldchanges group
1   Hspg2   0.004153    59.926384   g1
3   Serpinh1    0.007515    30.217304   g1
5   Lgr5    0.003352    15.884651   g1
7   Slc6a6  0.003947    99.277559   g1
8   Tpm1    0.000299    36.480099   g1
3   Fxyd3   0.000485    0.583842    g2
6   App 　　0.000566  23.006282   g2
0   Apoe    0.003422    11.763652   g3
1   Ltbp3   0.003203    25.222484   g3
9   Krt15   0.005134    80.433481   g3
```

Comment: This approach worked nicely, but I decided to use the melt function because it's more versatile when I have changing number of groups between my dataset. I was able to make this work for any number of groups by using a temporary dictionary and a for loop, but that just ended up making it slower (still a vast improvement over my original approach) :P